# Flex 4.7 Accessing another Application Storage Directory

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

Is it possible to access another .air application storage directory? Because when I do the following:

```
private var _installerFile:File = new File("app-storage:/");

var appDir = new File()
appDir = _installerFile.resolvePath("../../..");
```

I just want to go up from my storage directoy into the App Data and then inside another App directory.

Thanks for the help,
David

Comment: sounds like a security breach

Comment: Do you have the absolute path?  Can you access the other path directly; as opposed to relatively?

Comment: Yes, the system won't let you read other app's private data. If you control both apps, you can exchange files through external storage, where regular user files go. Anyways, if would help if you could provide more about the problem you're trying to solve.